# C# to call Cadence Allegro with SKILL code function

Tags: cadence

I am trying to make some calls to Cadence Allegro from C#, I have some C++ examples but they are very incomplete.  I don't see anything on S/O with this, some Allegro... But if anyone has ever called up a Allegro PCB etc.. , can you point me in the right direction?  I have been looking on Cadence website.

Looking to send "SKILL .il" code over from C# application to Cadence PCB / Editor etc.. for the .brd (board) files to show violations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Cadence Systems has a dll called mpsc.dll, and there is a header file  mpsc.h in which there are many functions to call.

This stuff does work, just very old and I will wrap it in C#

Comment: Yes, I don't recall the details as I'm on another contract at another company.

Comment: oh cool. I had a similar project, what i did was used skill's ipc commands to open a C# child app and worked from there.